# Would a printed copy of Meguillat Esther require genizah?

Tags: tanach, megillat-esther, genizah-storage

Meguillat Esther is, famously, the one Tanakh text in which the name of G-d is never mentioned. Suppose you had a worn-out printed copy. Could you dispose of it as you would any old book, given the fact that it does not include Shemot? Or would it, as  a holy text and/or an object used for a mitzvah (talmud Torah) require genizah?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rabbinical Assembly (Conservative) says [yes](https://www.rabbinicalassembly.org/sites/default/files/public/halakhah/teshuvot/20012004/Reisner%20Shemot.pdf).

Rabbi Joe Blair (Reform or Reconstructionist?) says [maybe](http://gamliel.institute/assets/genizah.pdf).

Din Online (Orthodox) says [certainly](http://din.org.il/2017/01/05/%D7%92%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%96%D7%AA-%D7%9E%D7%92%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%AA-%D7%90%D7%A1%D7%AA%D7%A8/).

Rashbatz (Shu"t Tashbetz 1:2, quoted by various later authorities) says it would require genizah miderabanan.

(All of these sources seem to be dealing with even a non-scroll version of Megillat Esther. Mishnah Berurah 154:22 says that a scroll version of any book of Tanach requires "strict genizah" (see [here](https://books.google.ca/books?id=YDoeeehJF-AC&pg=PA314&lpg=PA314&dq=tashmishei%20mitzvah%20genizah&source=bl&ots=N3zZpv5xxQ&sig=ACfU3U1EKQ_JBQtblIQxM2xAP6AxsUksTg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjTsbHmwIDgAhXH44MKHTG8BL0Q6AEwAnoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=strict%20genizah&f=false)))

Comment: I cannot imagine a more thoroughly researched answer to such a simple question. Most intriguingly, Reisner, one of your keffir sources, is the only one to bring the explicit Shulchan Aruch on this very issue. Thank you, @רבות!!

Comment: @josh you are of course welcome!